# Insert HTML into DIV with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is one of my first jquery scripts. I want to expand a DIV and load some external html into it. This is the code I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uhEgG/5/

This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var loadUrl = http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html

    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").hide();
    });

    $("#country").click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").show();
        $("#country_slide").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

});
```

The expanding did work but now it doesn't since adding the Ajax code. Can anyone show me hwere I am going wrong, and ideally highlight any thing I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: your url should be a string

Answer (score 0):

Just replace country click with this

```
$("#country").click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").show();
        $("#country_slide").load(loadUrl);
    });
```

and add quotes on url

```
var loadUrl = "http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you..

`var loadUrl = 'http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html';`

http://jsfiddle.net/APkHN/1/

your URL was not a string, and it was missing an end brace.

Answer (score 0):

put your url inside `''`

see it working here `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/uhEgG/8/

Also, you might need to delegate close like this (*As you are replacing html inside `#country_slide` which contains your `#close`*)

```
$("#country_slide").on('click','#close',function () {
        $("#country_slide").hide();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? Also, how come the content doesn't get loaded in? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uhEgG/9/

Comment: It seem's you are trying to load content from an external domain i.e `sheldonbrown.com` , Which is not possible because of same origin policy `-->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript